# Why does *words[] not equals **words?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array of char arrays:

```
char *words[] = {"word1", "word2", "word3"};
```

I learned that you can write *words to access the first value. So if I use *words, I will get "word1" since thats what words points at.

Why does this not work for this array?

```
char **words = {"word1", "word2", "word3"};
```

It seems like that this should do the same.

Comment: Stack allocation vs heap

Comment: array of pointers and pointer-to-pointer are not same

Comment: @self: What do you mean? Without context, your comment is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array can be initialized using the syntax:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

However, a pointer cannot be initialized using the syntax:

```
int* array = {1, 2, 3};
```

That's how the language is defined.

The same analogy applies to `words` in your posted code:

```
char *words[] = {"word1", "word2", "word3"};
```

initializes an array of `char*`.

```
char **words = {"word1", "word2", "word3"};
```

is not a supported syntax by the language to initialize a pointer to `char*`.

Comment: It always confuses me that the * is at the name and not at the type. Thanks

Comment: @DennisvonEich, I hope the answer helped a little bit.

Comment: @DennisvonEich: Whitespace is ignored. You can do `char *c;`, you can do `char* c`, you can to `char*c`.